# Cannot update itself in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Please see my sample as below:

```
create table tbl1(cl1 int,  cl2 varchar(10))
create table tbl2(cl1 int,  cl2 varchar(10))

insert tbl1
select 1, 'a' union all
select 1, 'b' union all
select 1, 'c' union all
select 1, 'd' union all
select 1, 'e' 

insert tbl2
select 1, '' union all
select 1, '' union all
select 1, 'c' union all
select 1, '' union all
select 1, 'a' 

select * from tbl1
select * from tbl2

update b
set b.cl2 = a.cl2
from tbl1 a inner join tbl2 b on a.cl1=b.cl1
where b.cl2 = '' and a.cl2 not in (select cl2 from tbl2 where tbl2.cl1 = a.cl1)
```

What I want is to update all empty value at cl2 column in tbl2 table with not duplicate values.

I tried to run as the script above, but it didn't work correct.

Please help me to find out the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: last select is for insert data to tbl2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.

```
create table #tbl1(cl1 int,  cl2 varchar(10))
create table #tbl2(cl1 int,  cl2 varchar(10))

insert #tbl1
select 1, 'a' union all
select 1, 'b' union all
select 1, 'c' union all
select 1, 'd' union all
select 1, 'e' 

insert #tbl2
select 1, '' union all
select 1, '' union all
select 1, 'c' union all
select 1, '' union all
select 1, 'a' 

    update b
    set b.cl2 = a.cl2
    from #tbl1 a inner join #tbl2 b on a.cl1=b.cl1
    where b.cl2 = '' and a.cl2 not in (select t.cl2 from #tbl2 t where a.cl1 = a.cl1) 

Select * from  #tbl1
Select * from  #tbl2
```

Comment: This will always true `where a.cl1 = a.cl1`

Comment: yes but it gives desired output as expected. you can remove where condition from subquery.

Comment: hi haresh hanat, I run your sample, the result is as my result. The value 'b' appear in 2 rows (row 1 and row 4). It still has duplicate data.